# Remove one row when it is added to different table

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have 2 tables

Registered events and events, but I want to show when a button is pressed it removes the event from the events into Registered events.
but i am unable to delete the event itself
can i hide it so it dosen't show up in the table on the webpage??

I am using CodeIgniter

![The event Graded Scratch Races at Cassey fields is in both tables] [1]

i don't have 10 reputation so here is a link to an image
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uzyvblmim0e1s5v/2015-05-19%2013_13_00-Eastern%20Veterans%20Cycling.png?dl=0

**Model**

```
function getAll()
{
// get all the records from the schools table

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('tblMeetRace as met');
$this->db->join('tblLocation as loc', 'loc.intLocationID = met.intLocationID');
$this->db->join('tblEvent as eve', 'eve.intEventID = met.intEventID');
//$this->db->Where('intMemberID = 1' );
$query = $this->db->get();


// if the number of rows returned is more than 0
if( $query->num_rows() > 0) {
    // loop through each record (row) and place that
    // record into an array called $data
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
}
$query->free_result();
// return the array to the controller
return $data;



function getAll1()
{
    // get all the records from the schools table

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tblMeetRace as met');
    $this->db->join('tblLocation as loc', 'loc.intLocationID = met.intLocationID');
    $this->db->join('tblRegistration as reg', 'reg.intMeetRaceID = met.intMeetRaceID');
    $this->db->join('tblEvent as eve', 'eve.intEventID = met.intEventID');
    $this->db->Where('intMemberID = 1' );
    $query = $this->db->get();

    // if the number of rows returned is more than 0
    if( $query->num_rows() > 0) {
        // loop through each record (row) and place that
        // record into an array called $data
        foreach ($query->result() as $row1) {
            $data1[] = $row1;
        }
    }
    $query->free_result();
    // return the array to the controller
    return $data1;
}
```

**controller**

```
public function getallevents() {
    $this->load->model('events_model');
    $data['records'] = $this->events_model->getAll();
    $data1['records1'] = $this->events_model->getAll1();
    $data3 = $data + $data1;
    $this->load->view('view-events', $data3);
}
```

**View**

```
        <!-- code for table of schools -->
    <div class="container proper-content">
        <div class="bs-example table-responsive">
            <h3>Unregistered Events</h3>
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead class="tablebackground">
                <tr>
                    <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;Meet race ID</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;Event Name</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;Location</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;Date</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;Time</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;Register</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                <?php

                foreach ($records as $row):
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td> $row->intMeetRaceID</td>";
                    //echo "<td> $row->intEventID</td>";
                    echo "<td> $row->strEventDescription</td>";
                    echo "<td> $row->strLocationName</td>";
                    echo "<td> $row->datDate</td>";
                    echo "<td> $row->timTime</td>";
                    echo "<td><a class='btn btn-success btn-sm'>Register</a></td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                endforeach;


                ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <h3>Registered Events</h3>

            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead class="tablebackground">
                <tr>
                 <!--   <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;User-ID #</th> -->
                    <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;Event Name</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;Location</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;Date</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;Time</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;UnRegister</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                    foreach ($records1 as $row1):
                        echo "<tr>";
                        //echo "<td> $row->intMemberID</td>";
                        //echo "<td> $row1->intEventID</td>";
                        echo "<td> $row1->strEventDescription</td>";
                        echo "<td> $row1->strLocationName</td>";
                        echo "<td> $row1->datDate</td>";
                        echo "<td> $row1->timTime</td>";
                        echo "<td><a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>Delete</a></td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                    endforeach;
```

Comment: Why have 2 tables? A single table to hold all the data would be more than adequate. Just add a field of registered with a value of either 0/1 or Y/N. Then it would be a simple matter of toggling this flag.

Comment: this is just my example i also have other tables and other information

Comment: think in procedures.  you need to read one, delete it, then write it to the other one, but if you want to make sure it's there you can do a where to make sure each field matches.

Comment: What about a trigger?

Answer (score 0):

despite the fact that you can do this things a lot easier, you can try to extend your first query like this - if i understand you correctly:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('tblMeetRace as met');
$this->db->join('tblLocation as loc', 'loc.intLocationID = met.intLocationID');
$this->db->join('tblEvent as eve', 'eve.intEventID = met.intEventID');
$this->db->join('tblRegistration as reg', 'reg.intMeetRaceID = met.intMeetRaceID', 'left');
$this->db->where(array("met.intMeetRaceID" => NULL));
```